# Adding if condition in layout xml file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, uicomponent

I want to add a if else condition statement in a layout xml file. I have to two uicomponent file.

```
if condition 1 then

  uicomponent file 1

else 

  uicomponet file 2
```

Any help.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this issue? If yes, please provide here for help to others as well.

Comment: No. If you find please post here